# Laravel Multiple Unions

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm having an issue adding a query with multiple Unions the "laravel way".

The I am trying to accomplish a query equivalent to the one generated by the following:

```
$ipsql = "";
for ($n = 1; $n < $total_networks; $n++) {
    $ipsql .= "(SELECT * FROM ip WHERE network = " . $n . " AND used = 0 LIMIT 5)
            UNION ALL";
}
if ($n == $total_networks) {
    $ipsql .= "(SELECT * FROM ip WHERE network = " . $n . " AND used = 0 LIMIT 3) ORDER BY ip_addr";
}
```

I haven't found an option for unions with Eloquent so I was attempting to use the query builder for this particular section but I keep running into an issue while using the builders unionAll.

Using this:

```
$ip_list = DB::table('ips')->where('network', '=', '0')->where('used', '=', '0')->limit(5);
        for($n = 1; $n < $network_count; $n++){
            $ip_list = DB::table('ips')->where('network', '=', $n)->where('used', '=', '0')->limit(5)->unionAll($ip_list);
        }
        $ips = $ip_list->get();
```

I keep getting a MySQL syntax error:

```
     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
     check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
     'union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = ? and `used` = ? limit 5) unio' at line 1 
    (SQL:
         (select * from `ips` where `network` = 16 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips`
         where `network` = 15 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 14
         and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 13 and `used` = 0 limit 5)
         union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 12 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select *
         from `ips` where `network` = 11 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where
         `network` = 10 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 9 and
         `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 8 and `used` = 0 limit 5)
 union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 7 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from
         `ips` where `network` = 6 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` =
         5 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 4 and `used` = 0 limit
         5) union all ((select * from `ips` where `network` = 3 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select *
         from `ips` where `network` = 2 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all ((select * from `ips` where
         `network` = 1 and `used` = 0 limit 5) union all (select * from `ips` where `network` = 0 and `used`
         = 0 limit 5)))))))))))))))))
```

I can see from the error that its nesting each new union call which is creating the syntax issue.
I tried accomplishing the same task with DB::raw but seem to be goofing that somewhere also. Is there a way to accomplish this thats better suited to laravel?
Thanks for looking!

Comment: I am having the same issue, please share if you have found a solution to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `unionAll` calls are indeed getting nested. One solution is to create a subquery in the `for` loop, and then `unionAll` that subquery to the main query *after* it's been defined. Then you run `get` on the whole shebang when you're done, like so:

```
$ips_list = DB::table('ips')->where('network', '=', '1')->where('used', '=', '0')->limit(5);

for($n = 1; $n < $total_networks; $n++){
    $ip_list_subquery = DB::table('ips')
             ->where('network', '=', $n)
             ->where('used', '=', '0')
             ->limit(5);
    $ips_list = $ips_list->unionAll($ip_list_subquery);
}
$ips = $ips_list->get();
```

So, effectively, you're chaining the `unionAll` calls:

`$a->unionAll($b)->unionAll($c)->unionAll($d)...`

rather than nesting them:

`$a->unionAll($b->unionAll($c->unionAll($d...))))`

Answer (score 0):

**// Use PDO . It is the simplest answer I found after two days of struggling for using complex UNION in Laravel**

```
 $PDO = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();

 $billingStmt = $PDO->prepare("

 select * from (SELECT   * 
 FROM     t_statements 
 WHERE    reference_id = $user_id 
 AND      service_provider='FOLDER' 
 AND      bill_name IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY bill_name ASC ) AS a 

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT * 
 FROM   ( 
 SELECT   * 
 FROM     t_statements 
 WHERE    reference_id = $user_id 
 AND      service_provider !='FOLDER' 
 AND      bill_name IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN is_paid = 0 THEN due_date ELSE is_paid END) DESC) b

     ");



        $billingStmt->execute();
        $usersBills = $billingStmt->fetchAll((\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $androidUserBills = json_encode($usersBills); // return results as json 

    return response($androidUserBills);
```

**// JSON response**

```
       [
             {
                  "id": "247",
                  "created_at": "2016-02-23 10:44:33",
                  "updated_at": "2016-02-23 16:58:57",
                  "t_user_account_id": "245",
                  "statement_date": null,
                  "due_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                  "amount": "0",
                  "is_paid": "0",
                  "is_reminded": "1",
                  "overdue": null,
                  "current_amount": null,
                  "bill_total": "88.5",
                  "bill_id": "zd91NwGU",
                  "bill_name": "Utility",
                  "predecessor": null,
                  "reference_id": "120",
                  "service_provider": "FOLDER",
                  "sp_id": null
                   },

             {
                  "id": "252",
                  "created_at": "2016-02-23 16:29:50",
                  "updated_at": "2016-02-23 16:58:25",
                  "t_user_account_id": "250",
                  "statement_date": null,
                  "due_date": "2016-03-04 17:52:34",
                  "amount": "0",
                  "is_paid": "0",
                  "is_reminded": "1",
                  "overdue": null,
                  "current_amount": null,
                  "bill_total": "88.5",
                  "bill_id": "Lojnc",
                  "bill_name": "Water bill",
                  "predecessor": null,
                  "reference_id": "120",
                  "service_provider": "IWK",
                  "sp_id": "7"
                    }

                    ]
```

Comment: This works but it's too much. You can just use DB::select("ANY RAW QUERY HERE");

Answer (score 0):

That works but it's too much. You can just use DB::select("ANY RAW Query");